# Precise placement of picture possible?

Tags: environments

To try to learn the *picture* environment, I decided to experiment with the placement of points on the page to see if I could really tell \LaTeX where to put stuff. What I found was that I can put stuff in correct *relation* to other stuff, but not in absolute positions on the page without nudging it to the correct location.

For example, the following code, which is intended to place a point at the upper left-hand corner of the page, does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0){\circle{1}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Instead, through some trial and error, I can basically get it to the upper left-hand corner with the following input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-.53,.34){\circle{1}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Is there an extra .53cm hidden somewhere in the horizontal direction, and .34cm in the vertical, or maybe some padding on whatever box is created for the picture environment?

How can I place a point ***exactly*** where I want it on a page?

I would like to do this without the use of non-standard packages; in other words, I'd like to understand "primitives" well enough to create a solution to this problem. I'm new to \LaTeX, but not to programming in general.

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case you're interested:  `pst-abspos`, a pstricks extension, can place objects at absolute positions on the page, using PostScript.

Comment: What is a `non-standard` package? Why is `geometry` apparently standard?

Comment: @cfr I would not consider geometry to be standard. Please provide any definitions that you think would be helpful.

Comment: What I mean is that you are using `geometry` but asking for no `non-standard` packages. That suggests you either think `geometry` is `standard` or also want a solution which does away with that package (but you don't say this).

Comment: @cfr I'm a newbie at \LaTeX so I used the `geometry` package only because I'm not aware of another or easier way to set the margin to zero. Assuming the way I've used the non-standard `geometry` package to set the margin to zero is functionally correct (it sets the margin to zero), the problem remains (i.e. regardless of the way in which I've set the margin to zero). Please share if you know the way to set the margin to zero with only "primitives," or if the `geometry` package does not do this correctly.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your suggestion. I'm sure it will be helpful.

Comment: What I'm saying is this: if you really want to do it with 'primitives' then you do not use LaTeX or, even plain. You just use the primitives from the base TeX. To use LaTeX is already to use a format: a set of macros built on top of the lower-level stuff, ultimately in terms of primitives. I think you may be confused about how the system works. Please correct me if I'm wrong. It just seems that way from your question and comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29314/discussion-between-jpf-and-cfr).

Answer (score 1):

You're telling that the picture takes no space; moreover you're placing the center of the circle in the wrong place and you're forgetting about the indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\noindent
\begin{picture}(1,1)
\put(0.5,0.5){\circle{1}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Note that no glue is inserted from `\topskip`, because the picture height is larger than its value.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the note about the indentation. Using your example, however, if I try `\put(0,0){\circle{1}}` it doesn't place the circle at (0,0). Have you tried `\put(.5,.5){\circle{1}}\put(.5,.5){\circle*{1}}`? Why is the solid circle smaller than the other?

Comment: The `\noindent` is important here.

Comment: @jpf Circles are available only at discrete sizes and LaTeX uses the largest one that doesn't go beyond the stated diameter; there are less filled circle than hollow ones. If you load `pict2e`, you get circles with “true” diameter, both hollow and filled.